# I have install npm install fontawesome-free, still gives me this error

Tags: angular

> 'ERROR in multi ../NGRX-Products/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss ../NGRX-Products/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss ../NGRX-Products/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss ./src/styles.scss'

Following files included in the style.scss

```
@import 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
```

I run npm install font-awesome --save-dev on my angulas.json

```
"styles": ["../NGRX-Products/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
    "../NGRX-Products/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
                  "../NGRX-Products/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesom`enter code here`e-free/scss/solid.scss",
                  "src/styles.scss"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular-fontawesome.  Here are the instructions:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome.